# Inspect element code and view page source code of a web page

Tags: css, selenium, html

what is the difference between inspect element code and view page source code 
  of a web page?

```
 <!doctype html><html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo"><!-- sp:feature:head-start -->
```

Comment: You can inspect your codes in **Inspect**, plus it is in the dev tools. **View Page Source** just shows you the rendered code

Answer (score 0):

**View Source Code**

This will Simply bring up all the HTML code, along with links to CSS files, Javascript, images, etc.
so that You can now read through it and see what that page is created with.

**Inspect Element**

If you want to drill down on a specific part of a page, most browsers now come with built-in inspectors. Or you can use Firebug in Firefox.

The respective code will be high-lighted in the left window. Then you can click on the tags outside of it or within it to drill down on those. As you do that, it will high-light the part of the page it controls.

On the right side, you'll see the CSS styles that are applied to the HTML tag that's high-lighted.

This is an extremely useful and quick way to inspect code.